# Caching using Spring Boot - What is ~keys in Redis key name?

Tags: caching, spring-boot, redis

When I tried to show the keys from redis-cli, the keys that generated from my application method generated *cachename~keys*, what is ~keys? I used Spring Boot *@Cacheable* annotation with custom keys and it showed those. I tried googling but there isn't any answer. Is it a wildcard of keys?? how can I show it all?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set parameter "usePrefix" as true in your CacheManager bean. This will prepend cacheName in your keys.

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager">
 ...
 <property name="usePrefix"><value>true</value></property>
 ...
</bean>
```